# let compiler optimize generalized class for spezific sizes (like a template)

Tags: templates, c++11, optimization

I have programmed a class revolving around arbitrary sized Matrices. My question now is, though I could hardly articulate it in a title, whether there is some way to let the compiler create an extra version of lets say 3X3 or 4X4 matrices where for example all the loops would be optimized away. My problem is very time critical so it would be amazing if there was some way to let the compiler degeneralize my matrix functions for those popular cases without having to maintain 3 Versions of the same algorithms in a fashion similiar to a template approach.

I would be really glad if someone could give me recommendations regarding this problem though I dont think it can be solved quite as a template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like Eigen does for dimension parameters: Make them a template parameter, but provide a special value for dynamically provided values:

```
template <int N> struct X
{
    X() : data{} {}

    static std::size_t size() { return N; }

    int data[N];

    void compute() { for (int : data) { /* ... */ } }
};

template <> struct X<-1>
{
    X(int n) : len(n), data(n) {}

    std::size_t size() const { return data.size(); }

    std::vector<int> data;

    void compute() { for (int : data) { /* ... */ } }
};
```

The common code could be moved into base class template or base class, e.g. using CRTP:

```
template <typename D>
struct Compute
{
    void compute()
    {
        D & d = static_cast<D &>(*this);
        for (int n : d.get_data()) { /* do stuff with n */ }
    }
};

template <int N> struct X : Base<X>
{
    // as above
};

template <> struct X<-1> : Base<X>
{
    // as above
};
```

Comment: Wait, why would you use `int` and partially specialize for `-1` instead of using `size_t` and providing a second class (template), appropriately named?

Comment: @Columbo: Just for notational symmetry - so you could say `X<10>, `X<15>, `X<Dynamic>`. No profound reason.

Comment: Ok this is great I did´nt know about integer templates before. I tried to compile it but I get errors with the initializers so I dropped them, it seems to work properly but I cant get code to be shared between the classes. The simplest way I can think of would be to just substitute the code into both functions using preprocessor makros but that seems dirty or is it?

Comment: @user5716904: You could use a base class template, like in the CRTP. I added an example. You either need to have an accessor for the data, or otherwise make the base template a friend.